# Using binary entropy function to approximate log(N choose K)

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

I am not a mathematician and struggling with the exercises while reading this book

[Information Theory, Inference and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/).

The author introduced the binary entropy function at the start of the book as

$$
H \equiv x \log \frac{1}{x} + (1-x) \log \frac{1}{(1-x)}
$$

He shows it can be used to approximate

$$
\log \binom{N}{r} \simeq NH(\frac{r}{N})
$$

I am puzzled how he got to this approximation. Please could someone explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is most likely that the author uses Stirling's approximation to the logarithm of the factorial function as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), where we use

$$\log n!\simeq n\log n - n+ O(\log n)$$
Thus, omitting the $O(\log)$ term on the assumption that it is negligible relative to the other terms, the approximation becomes (the blue terms below which sum to zero are added to obtain the desired result)
$$\log {N \choose r}=\log\frac{N!}{r!(N-r)!}\simeq N\log N-N-r\log r+r-(N-r)\log(N-r)+(N-r)\\=N\log N-N-r\log r+r-(N-r)\log(N-r)+(N-r)\color{blue}{+r\log N-r\log N}\\=r\log\frac{N}{r}+(N-r)\log\frac{N}{N-r}\\=N\frac{r}{N}\log\frac{N}{r}+N\frac{N-r}{N}\log\frac{N}{N-r}\\=N\left(\frac{r}{N}\log\frac{1}{\frac{r}{N}}+\left(1-\frac{r}{N}\right)\log\frac{1}{1-\frac{r}{N}}\right)\\=NH\left(\frac{r}{N}\right)$$

Comment: +1. See eg chapter 1 of David MacKay's "Information Theory, Inference and Learning Algorithms" http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itprnn/ps/5.16.pdf where the next term in the approximation is given.

Comment: @leonbloy: thanks for the link to the PDF.

Comment: So all I needed to do is plug Stirling's approximation into the log of factorial function, added the extra terms and then do algebra to get the answer?

Comment: @algolicious: Yes, that sounds right.