# Counting samples that are different in the given percentage of elements

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs, mixing

Suppose there are *n* unique *elements*. A *mix* is a set of *m* elements pulled from the *elements* without replacement, so that there are $ C^{m}_{n} $ possible *mixes* in total. Suppose one has all such mixes. Let call a *mix* to be *distinct* from some others if, at least, 50% of its elements are not present in any other *mix* (pairwise comparison of mizes).

How many of $ C^{m}_{n} $ mixes are *distinct mixes*? Or, in other words, let **N** be a *set* of mixes. Lets call **N** a *valid mix*, if all mixes therein are pairwise *distinct*. How many mixes are in the largest possible *valid set*?

I will be happy with rough estimation for large n and m (say, $10^5$ and $10^{4}$ correspondingly), but, preferably, without assuming n>>m. All methods I tried seem to heavily underestimate the number, and counting them by brutal force on computer takes too much time.

Comment: Let **N** be a *set* of mixes. Lets call **N** a *valid* set if all *mixes* therein are pairwise distinct. Then my question is: how many mixes are in the largest possible *valid* set? @Henry

Comment: This is related to [constant-weight codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-weight_code) of given length (your $n$) and weight (your $m$) and minimum distance.  Upper and lower bounds seem to have been calculated for small values

Comment: Thank you for the reference, was not awere of that. But it seems that there aren't any known approximations, only brute force results for rather small **n** and **m**. Tough problem, it seems. @Henry

Comment: See https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/Andw.html for more known bounds. This is indeed a hard problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the set of mixes be $\{M_1,\dots,M_{\binom{n}{m}}\}$. Each mix-set $S_j$ can contain some subset of these mixes.
There are $2^{\binom{n}{m}}$ possible mix-sets $\{S_j\}$. Some of these are valid. We wish to find $max(\enspace|S_j|\enspace \big| S_j \text{ is valid})$.

We can draw a large graph to represent the possible mixes as follows. Let each node represent a mix.
We draw an edge from $M_i$ to $M_j$, if they differ by more than 50% of elements.

Now it's easy to see that your problem is to find the size of the largest clique in this graph. Since you are looking for an approximation for large $m,n$, one can find this by assuming a random graph, by

1. Finding the probability of an edge $p_e$ between any two vertices
2. Given $p_e$, and number of nodes $\binom{n}{m}$, finding bounds for the largest clique in this random graph.

We can calculate $p_e$ as follows. Fix some node, ie some mix of m elements from n. Then to see nodes that differ from this by half the elements, we can choose $m$ elements from at most $n-\frac{m}{2}$ elements. Thus the probability of an edge is
$$p_e = \frac{\binom{n-\frac{m}{2}}{m}}{\binom{n}{m}}$$
Note that this works, irrespective of which fraction of $\frac{m}{2}$ elements we exclude

For the second part, we have the following theorem:
For $G\in\mathcal{G}_{n,p}$, for any $p\in (0,1)$, the clique number is almost surely $\sim 2log_{\frac{1}{p}}(n)$

Then as per the theorem, our clique number is
\begin{align*}
C &= 2log_{\frac{1}{p_e}}\left(\binom{n}{m}\right)\\
&=2\frac{log\left(\binom{n}{m}\right)}{log(\frac{1}{p_e})}\\
&=2\frac{log\left(\binom{n}{m}\right)}{log\left(\frac{\binom{n}{m}}{\binom{n-\frac{m}{2}}{m}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{2}{1-k}
\end{align*}

Where $k = log(\binom{n-\frac{m}{2}}{m})/log(\binom{n}{m})$.

---

There are many ways to approximate k. For example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835017/using-binary-entropy-function-to-approximate-logn-choose-k).
But in all such cases, one notes that $k\sim 1$ for the kind of $m,n$ values you mention.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have little expertise in graph theory, but the solution sounds beautiful and reasonable.